# Can I remotely trigger a SUNPAC NE-i flash (dedicated for Nikon DSLR's) using a FlashPoint wireless transmitter & receiver?

Tags: off-camera-flash, ttl

I use Nikon D850 with other FlashPoint flashes. I have this older Sunpak NE-i that I used with a Nikon D200. Wondering if anyone has any experience triggering these with wireless remote like Flashpoint R2 i-TTL 2.4G Wireless Receiver For Nikon Flashes?

Answer (score 1):

Provided the triggering voltage of the Sunpak NE-i does not exceed the capacity of the Flashpoint (Godox) receiver to tolerate voltage, it *should* work in any mode for which the flash is capable when used directly on the camera's hot shoe. With two different third party products from two different makers, *should* doesn't always happen, though. At the very least, you almost certainly could fire the flash in sync with the camera's shutter using manual power mode.